# Windows USB Driver with express edition or MINGW?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, wdk

I am a newbie windows developer

I am a Linux developer and sadly have to port my USB driver to Windows or redevelop the same. I would like to do it using some free tools. I will be doing the same on Windows and the driver has to work on Windows 8, 8.1. So my starting point is to use WinDDK.

I prefer to do a UMDF for the USB device

Now my question:

1. Can I use Visual Studio Express edition? - too expensive to buy professional
2. Can I use MinGW?
3. Or what is the prefered tool chain?

Comment: WinDDK includes its own compiler/linker/etc., or at least it used to.  You shouldn't need anything else apart from an IDE.

Comment: So I can develop a module with WinDDK and use makefile and VI? Can you please point me to an example which i can use as a starting point

Comment: The WinDDK also contains sample code.